# Issue on importing Bitbucket issues to JIRA

Tags: bitbucket, jira

I'm trying to import Bitbucket issues to my On-Demand JIRA instance however it always fails when I select a project to import throwing:

> Fetching data from Bitbucket failed:
>   org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem
>   while creating a connection to the remote service. (the complete
>   exception can be found in the log)

Comment: This is a recently introduced issue. Please keep tabs on that here: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/8604/bitbucket-issue-importer-exporter-is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As thankfully referenced by [Jason](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52788/issue-on-importing-bitbucket-issues-to-jira#comment42541_52788), the issue was that the [Bitbucket issue importer / exporter [has been] broken (BB-9691)](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/8604/bitbucket-issue-importer-exporter-is), which has been resolved as of 2014-01-06.